# Having trouble connecting to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm working on an application written in VB6 and I'm having trouble connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database that has been set up on a server in our office.

Here are the symptoms:

- When I try to connect using a connection string via ADO in VB6, VB6 hangs and then finally gives me the error: "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied."
- if I make a blank .udl file and double-click on it, in the Connection tab of the Data Link Properties dialog, in the dropdown where it says "Select or enter a server name", if I click on the dropdown to see the list or click the "Refresh" button, it hangs.
- When I try to connect via SQL Server 2005 Management Studio (SQL Server 2005 is installed on the client machine on which I am working on the VB6 program), when I try to connect via:

  - **TCP/IP**: I get the message "This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers. (ConnectionDlg)"
  - **Shared Memory**: I get the message "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 41 - Cannot open a Shared Memory connection to a remote SQL server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)"
  - **Named Pipes**: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326)"

Here are some of the common proposed solutions I have seen online which I have implemented (and of course have not as of yet solved the problem):

- Remote connections have been enabled in SQL Server 2008
- telnetting to port 1433 gives me a blank screen (i.e., it connects, it doesn't give me an error)
- netstat -a on the server shows that TCP port 1433 is open
- Mixed Authentication is already set up on SQL Server 2008 so it can accept either Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication

I'm really at the end of my rope and have no idea where to go with this, since I don't know where (or even if) there are detailed logs that I can browse that will tell me when a connection attempt starts and what happens each step of the way. I'm hoping there's a simple fix for this that I'm not knowledgeable enough to know of.

*Update*: Here are answers to the follow-up questions asked so far:

- OS: Vista 64-bit, on both client and server
- SQL Browser Server is running on the server, according to SQL Server Configuration Manager
- Connection String - the line in question in the VB program is thus:
  fooSQL.Open "SERVER=SERVERNAME;DRIVER=SQL Server;DATABASE=DATABASENAME", username, password
  (where fooSQL is an ADODB.Connection)
- still happens when Firewall is turned off on either client or server (or both)

*re: MDAC*

as per [This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components#Which_Version_do_I_have.3F) I checked HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\DataAccess\FullInstallVer and the value is "6.0.6001.18000". I also ran Component Checker and on startup when I click "Perform analysis of your machine and automatically determine the release version", I get the following message after I click "OK":

"The following product releases were matched:

UNKNOWN"

*Update: SQL Services*
re: gator's comment, here are the SQL Services running on the server in Computer Management > Services

- SQL Active Directory Helper Service
- SQL Full-Text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER)
- SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
- SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)
- SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)
- SQL Server Browser
- SQL Server Integration Services 10.0
- SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
- SQL Server VSS Writer

Comment: I'd suggest posting the connection string you're using here...it's a big piece in the puzzle.

Comment: Do you have the SQL Browser server running on your server?

Comment: what os is the client machine you are connecting from?

Comment: What version of MDAC do you have on the client?

Comment: The connection string you posted - is it LITERALLY your connection string?  Is your server really called 'SERVERNAME' and the database 'DATABASENAME'?

Comment: I'm having the exact same error now! same specs.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure of the following:

- Windows Firewall is not blocking port 1433 (or the TCP port you set up for SQL Server)
- The SQL Browser Service is running on the server (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try installing the sql 2008 management studio and connecting with that from the vb6 machine over TCPIP. I would also try installing the latest (2008) ODBC drivers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Was SQL Server 2008 installed as a default instance or a named instance?  If it is a named instance, then you will need to tweek your connection string a bit to talk to it.

When you RDP to the box, can you authenticate using the client tools to the local SQL Server instance?

Comment: can I buy some pot from you?

:p

No, seriously - I'm sure what youre saying is helpful, I just have within epsilon of no idea what you're talking about. Could you dumb it down significantly for me? 

For starters, how do I find out if SQL Server 2008 was installed as a default or named instance?

Comment: "This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers. (ConnectionDlg)"

Are the SQL 2005 client tools you are using up to Service Pack 3?

When you RDP to the box, can you use the local tools to connect? if so, do they do a "\\servername\SQLServerName"  type connection or just 'localhost' type connection?

Also, when you view the services running on the computer in "Computer Management",  does it list the SQL Server as "SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)" or does it have other stuff associated with it?

Comment: Yes, Service Pack 3 has been installed.

I still don't know how to see if they do a "\\servername\SQLServerName' or "localhost" connection. In the login screen that pops up when you run SQL Server Management Studio, in the "Server" text box I type in "SERVERFOO-PC" (the server name), if that's what you mean.

- I also updated the question proper with a list of the SQL services running in Computer Management > Services since I don't have enough space to do so in this comment (but the short answer is "it's more than just SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)")

Answer (score 0):

Jordan (or others reading this in the future), at least one solution to a problem like this is to be sure to specify both the servername AND the instance name (even though various tools, like the Migration Assistance, or connection strings, like that shown above) just prompt for servername alone.

So for instance, in your case, it would seem it should have been serverfoo-pc\mssqlserver. Or one running Express would use servername\sqlexpress, or if one had changed the instance name to something else, use that. And if the client tool is on the same box as SQL Server, you could use .\ instead of servername\, as in .\sqlexpress.

I think this was what Gator was getting at, but in your back and forth this clarification was not made. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One of the very important issues is related to installing Active Directory after MSSQLSERVER!
First of all I should write that you will receive a message from MS SQL if you want to install it **after** Active Directory! So you need to install MS SQL before AD.

**After checking usual issues such as:**

1- Allow remote connection to this server in "SQL Manager" by right click on the Server name and click on "Properties" and then selecting "Connection' from left menu.

2- Enable TCP/IP in "SQL Server Network Configuration" of "SQL Server Configuration Manager".

3- Enable Named Pipes in "SQL Server Network Configuration" of "SQL Server Configuration Manager".

4- Be sure "SQL Server Browser" is started in "SQL Server Services" of "SQL Server Configuration Manager".

5- Open Port 1433 (default) for MSSQLSERVER in "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security on Local Computer"

Finally please be sure Active Directory is Active.

My problem was, I removed Active Directory but I forgot users are still in Domain space, so I must reinstall again "Active Directory Domain Service".

Best Regard